# Group multiple shortcode inside content using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

I have multiple shortcode inside the content that look like this:

```
[mygroup group-name-1]
    
    [file* field-name-134 limit:200]
    
        [mygroup group-name-2]
            [file* field-name-135 limit:200]    
        [/mygroup]
    
[/mygroup]
```

I need help capturing whole group and the content using php regex.

Expected result:

```
[mygroup group-name-1]
    [file* field-name-134 limit:200]
[/mygroup]

[mygroup group-name-2]
    [file* field-name-135 limit:200]    
[/mygroup]
```

I have the following regex `preg_match_all('/\\[mygroup +(.*?)\\]/', $shortcode, $matches)` but it only captures group tag and their name.

$matches result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [mygroup group-name-1]
            [1] => [mygroup group-name-2]           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => group-name-1
            [1] => group-name-2            
        )

)
```

I also tried using this pattern `/\\[mygroup +(.*?)\\](.*?)\\[/mygroup\\]\/` but it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `file` check in your regex as well. Something like this should get you closer:

```
preg_match_all('/\\[mygroup +([^]]+?)\\]\s*\\[(file\\*[^]]+?)\]/', '[mygroup group-name-1]
    
    [file* field-name-134 limit:200]
    
        [mygroup group-name-2]
            [file* field-name-135 limit:200]    
        [/mygroup]
    
[/mygroup]', $matches);
```

You then can use indices 1 and 2 for the `group` and `file` values.

PHP demo: https://3v4l.org/EeFrZ

If you have a question about regex changes please comment, a description of it can be seen here https://regex101.com/r/uLjIzg/1/.